# Spring AsyncTaskExecutor Returns Futures That Don't Throw Exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous, future

If I submit a `Callable` task to Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` (the default implementation of `AsyncTaskExecutor`), I receive a `Future` representing the result of the computation. I know that my callable will throw an exception, but when I call `Future#get`, the method returns `null` instead of throwing an exception. I have found this to be the case when I invoke `AsyncTaskExecutor#submit` directly, and when it is used implicitly through Spring's `@Async` annotation.

In the source for `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, I see there's an `ErrorHandler` instance variable that seems to control how the futures throw exceptions. I tried wiring in a custom `ErrorHandler` that would rethrow any exception it received as a `RuntimeException`, but for some reason that didn't work. When I sent a request to my running application's endpoint, it timed out. My app printed no logs; not even the ones Spring normally prints before the request hits my REST controller. Note that I wired my `ErrorHandler` directly into the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` bean. I didn't define the `ErrorHandler` itself as a bean.

```java
public class DataRetriever {
    @Autowired 
    private AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public List<Data> getData(String id) throws Exception {
      Future<List<Data>> futureData = getDataEventually(id);
      return futureData.get(); // exception should be thrown here
    }  

    private Future<List<Data>> getDataEventually(
        return taskExecutor.submit(() -> throw new RuntimeException());
    }
}
```

Comment: if you provide a one-file program that demonstrates the issue, then probably someone would find a fix.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Just added, thanks.

Comment: this is not a complete program - it has no main method. I cannot run it.